# Can a nonholomorphic function times nonholomorphic become holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I think it may be possible but I have no idea about it.

Comment: The functions $e^{\overline{z}}$ and $e^{-\overline{z}}$ are not holomorphic and their product is the constant function 1.

Comment: For any holomorphic function $f$ consider the product of $g(z) := \exp \bar z$ and $f / g$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider **any** function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}_{\not=0}$. Regardless of what $f$ is, the function $g:z\mapsto {1\over f(z)}$ is defined everywhere and we always have $f(z)\cdot g(z)=1$.

Now just pick some really nasty $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}_{\not=0}$ - for example, send $z$ to $1$ if $z\in\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and to $2$ otherwise (this is a version of the Dirichlet function). Then neither $f$ nor $g$ is holomorphic.

---

In general, it's usually very easy to combine two "nasty" things to get a "nice" thing (e.g. the sum of two irrationals can be rational) since we can often get a "nicely cancelling" situation.